# I know v-table within vuetify behave diiferently compare to html table tag, but what's actually the difference?

Tags: html-table, vue-component, vuetify.js

take follow vue.file for example:

```
<script setup></script>

<template>
  <v-app class="main-app">
    <v-table class="Table v-table">
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
    </v-table>
    <v-divider class="my-5"></v-divider>
    <table class="Table n-table">
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.Table th,
.Table td,
.Table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.Table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
```

it render differently in browsers. When I opened the dev tool, noticed that user agent stylesheet setting had been overwritten by new css(table tag), while v-table didn't.
but there only be  user agent stylesheet and the style added from above.